# Without user loging inner page is disable wordpress

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, logging

I want to disable the inner pages of my web-site for users who are not logged in.
Non-logged in users should not be able to see any content and should get a message "Please Log in to access this content."

**Ex.**
If the user is not logged in and opens the about us page, they should see a message to please log in first,
and should not see the contents of the page. When user is logged in and clicks on the about us page, they should see all contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php     
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
?> 
<style>
.lor1{ display:none;}
.lor1.kun{ display: block;}
.lor1.user_not_login{ display: block;}
</style>
<?php
```

}  ?>

**I got the Answer its easy by css..**

1. main div(.lor1) means comman div start after **header** and finesh before **footer**
2. Add new class (.lor1.kun) in main div when user loging this main class display: block;
3. make new html Ex. display mess loging frist one (.lor1.user_not_login)

**ADD this code in header.php**

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user [is logged in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) and [filter the content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) accordingly:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'so20656342_restrict_content', 999, 1 );
function so20656342_restrict_content( $content )
{
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        $content = 'Please log in to access this content';

    return $content;
}
```